# How do I set the node path with a contextual filter?

Tags: 7, views

I'm creating a simple job board for my company in Drupal 7 w/ Views.  I have a view which creates a page that lists all available jobs.  Within each job is a truncated description which I have set to trim and display a "Read More" link which goes to the details of the job posting.

To generate the "Read More" link, I am using a contextual filter which pulls the [nid] and in the 'body' section I have the "Read More" link set to node/[nid].  This works exactly the way I need it to.

The issue I'm having is that I have created another page within the view to display the full job posting.  And instead of going to www.mydomain.com/node/3166, I want it to go to something like www.mydomain.com/jobs/current/posting/3166.  (I'd like to use the nid as some jobs might have the same title).

I go into this view and set the path to 'node/%' and the view shows up formatted and everything when details are clicked, however, setting this bombs out ALL of my other content within the site.  So I tried setting the path to something like 'jobs/current/posting/%' and I just can't get it to work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and/or have a solution or workaround??  TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all you don't need Contextual filter in your first case where you are generating link as "node/[nid]" , what you need is replacement pattern. Todo this you can simply add nid to fields list and place above read more link and use the pattern.
- Change read more link to "jobs/current/posting/[nid]"

Regarding what you are trying to solve

- You cannot have a view with path "node/%" since it's already taken by node module to render node pages. It will conflict with node module and as you said "bombs out ALL of my other content"
- In your view set path as 'jobs/current/posting/%'
- Add a contextual filter nid and set provide default value to content id from URL as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Hey Anil,

Thanks so much for your reply.  You're right on the contextual filter on the first part...i just had my description wrong and was not using a contextual filter.

On the problem at hand, I have everything set up as you describe, however, the view still is not showing up when I click on the "More" link.  Obviously, I have something set up wrong.  Is there anything else I need to check or get set up??

Comment: Can you give me "More link" path ?

Comment: sure it's:  jobs/current/posting/[nid].  I have tried both like that and with a / in front of 'jobs'...still no dice.

Comment: Okay, i've been playing around with it and this is getting strange.  If I go into a job post and change the URL alias (which is created by auto-aliasin) in include a "/" at the front, it works..however, now I'm stuck with 2 slashes after my domain name like so:  http://www.mydomain//jobs/current/posting/3157. It also gives me an error about being in an infinite loop.  Any way to get rid of the second slash?

Comment: You don't need to change URL alias.. Just point read more link to jobs/current/posting/[nid] .. Let there be node page and view page...

Comment: Separating the pages out to having a node page and view page has fixed the issue. Thanks for your help.